# Is there a standard header to clear cache for arbitrary URLs in a RESTful API

Tags: rest, http, caching

I'm looking to implement a thin client around a RESTful(or a close attempt) API.

I'd like the client to cache the API responses where appropriate but to reduce the logic in the client I would also like the backend to handle the cache clear logic.

Lets say we have a resource "item list" at

`example.com/items/`

CRUD methods (GET,PUT, and DELETE) can be called on

`example.com/items/{id}`

Now, as you've already guessed, adding and removing items will also change the full list response.  In this example we want to clear the cache for the list response after a DELETE call to an item.  Is there a standard way to clear the cache on arbitrary urls?

I'm imagining something like `Clear-Caches: ../items/`

Is there another way to do this?  If this doesn't exist, why not?  Perhaps this is a bad pattern for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a standard header to clear cache for arbitrary URLs in a RESTful API

No.

As far as I can tell, the [Linked Cache Invalidation](https://mnot.github.io/I-D/linked-cache-inv/) draft expired in March.  That approach is close to what you are after, I think, but doesn't seem to have gotten any traction in the standardization process.